# Creating PolylineZM from Points using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, linear-referencing, polyline-creation

I have a point feature class that is essentially hundreds of vertices along a single line.  The Attribute Table contains MD (Measured Depth) values, XY fields of each point feature, and a ID field for that line.

Is this enough information to create a PolylineZM featureclass?

My end game is to use a table (has a single record matching the ID of the line and a Minimum and Maximum value that should both be along the line) and cut a smaller segment from the line using those two values (aka Make Route event layer).  My issue is producing a PolylineZ or PolylineZM that I can use for this routing method.  I tried Points to Line but it only produces a Polyline.

Once I have the correct Polyline type I believe I should be able to "route" down the lines measurements correctly and clip.

[image]

Comment: Try the Point to Polyline tool in the ET GeoWizard.  Looks like they have some parameters to retain Z/M geometries, https://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/UserGuide/convertPnt2Pl.htm

Comment: @artwork21- thanks and I have used ETGeowizards before but unfortunately I do not have it at the current place of work.  I'll look into obtaining it but if there is another solution, I'm very interested

Comment: also would I use my MD values mentioned above as the Z and the M values?

Comment: This worked artwork21.  Can You supply this as answer and I'll accept it when the 2 day limit is up?  I was able to get a polylineZM using ETGeo and I could do my clipping correctly after the fact.  I'll get in touch with ianko to see pricing for ETGeo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment;

Try the Point to Polyline tool with ET GeoWizard. Looks like they have some parameters to retain Z/M geometries:

https://ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/UserGuide/convertPnt2Pl.htm